# pipe process communication parent to child permission denied

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

When I build and run this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int pipefd[2], pid, n, rc, nr, status;
    char *teststring = "Hello World\n", buf[1024];
    rc = pipe(pipefd);

    if(rc < 0) {
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1], teststring, strlen(teststring));
        close(pipefd[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    // parent's code
    close(pipefd[1]);
    n = strlen(teststring);
    nr = read(pipefd[0], buf, nr);
    rc = write(1, buf, nr);
    wait(&status);
    printf("Good Work child\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it fails with a "permission denied" message.

I am testing on Elementary OS Freya (Linux), and I see the same behavior running under Netbeans and running from a terminal.

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: GCC complains to me about an incompatible implicit declaration of `printf()`, because you have failed to include `stdio.h`.  That seems unlikely to be the source of your problem, however, and in fact your program runs apparently fine for me either way, producing the same output.

Comment: "Permission denied" seems an odd error -- are you sure you are running the *compiled program*, and in fact the specific one resulting from the code you presented?  I assumed so in my edit, but perhaps that was mistaken: if you are trying to execute the source code as if it were a program, then you might indeed get a "permission denied" error.

Comment: `nr = read(pipefd[0], buf, nr);` I think `nr` is uninitialized here.  Did you want `nr = read(pipefd[0], buf, n)`?

Comment: i don't know why i am getting permission denied from IDE's 
i have test this code on Code::Blocks and Netbeans 

but form terminal i am getting the desired result 
@NateEldredge was also right 
one mistake was in this line
nr = read(pipefd[0], buf, nr);
here i have to pass n the length of string but i was passing nr by mistake 

Now i am getting the result from terminal but why not from IDE's ?